# Initializing Object Dependent on Another Object

Tags: scala

Given:

**src/main/scala/net/Foo.scala**

```
package net

object Foo {
  ???
  val x = 100
}
```

**src/main/scala/net/Bar.scala**

```
package net

object Bar {
 import Foo._
 def speak = "bar!"
}
```

I opened up the REPL to call `Bar#speak`:

```
scala> import net.Bar
import net.Bar

scala> Bar.speak
res0: String = bar!
```

I had expected Bar to have initialized `Foo`, resulting in an exception getting thrown with `???`.

Why wasn't this exception thrown?

Comment: Imports never have effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you had:

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   ???
     |   val x = 100
     | }
defined object Foo

scala> object Bar {
     |  import Foo._
     |  def speak = "bar!"
     | }
defined object Bar

scala> Bar.speak
res0: String = bar!

scala> Bar.speak
res1: String = bar!
```

`import Foo._` means that for compilation purposes to resolve names members of Foo will be available in the scope.
It does not mean that `Foo` has to be initialized at this point - Scala is being lazy here.
Now contrast with this example:

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   ???
     |   val x = 100
     | }
defined object Foo

scala> object Bar {
     |   val blowUp = Foo.x
     |   def speak = "bar!"
     | }
defined object Bar

scala> Bar.speak
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  ... 37 elided
```

It forces `Foo` to get initialized because it uses `Foo.x` in its own initialization which in turn is triggered by
calling `speak`. Simplified example:

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   ???
     |   val x = 100
     | }
defined object Foo
```

Didn't blow up yet. `Foo` is not initialized.

```
scala> Foo.x
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  ... 35 elided
```

Now we forced `Foo` to get initialized.

In short there are 2 important things here: 1) lazy initialization upon reference/call and 2) import does not cause initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Bar` doesn't actually refer to `Foo` anywhere. If `Bar.speak` used `Foo` or `Foo.x` in some way, you would get the expected exception. `import` puts `Foo`'s members into scope, but doesn't access them.